# IE9 not rendering CSS file properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

New to the site, hope somebody can help me.

I'm designing a new site using CSS3 and HTML5 (not a wizard in either, but getting the basics down), but for some reason, when I view a basic layout in IE9, it will not display colours or formatting properly. The same page will show as requested in Chrome and in Firefox. Could somebody please assist me on this?

I'll post code below, just a very basic layout with testing colours and sample text. Thanks.

`

### HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">


<title>Testing123.com</title>

</head>

<body>
    <header id="mainHeader"><h1>TestSite123.com</h1>
        <nav id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li>item3</li>
                <li>item4</li>
                <li>item5</li>
                <li>item6</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <aside id="lhs">
        <h2>Recent1</h2>
        <h2>Recent2</h2>
        <h2>Recent3</h2>
    </aside>
    <content id="Content">
        <h2>News</h2>
        <h2>Misc</h2>
    </content>
    <aside id="rhs">
        Right Side
    </aside>
    <footer id="mainFooter">Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS CODE

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*limited reset*/
html, body, div, section, article, aside, header, hgroup, footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, address, time, span, em, strong, img, ol, ul, li, figure, canvas, video, th, td, tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


header#mainHeader {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 140px;
    position: relative; 
}

header#mainHeader h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Arial;
    }


nav#mainNav ul, ul.menu {
    list-style: none;
    }

nav#mainNav {
    background-color: #e3e6eb;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 54px;
    margin-bottom: none;

    }

header#mainHeader nav ul {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1px;

}

header#mainHeader nav li {
    float: right;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 12px;
}

aside#lhs{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: brown;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    float: left;
    }

content#Content {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    }

aside#rhs{
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    }

footer#mainFooter {
    clear: both;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }
/*end of css file*/`
```

Comment: Did a jsfiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/9U8U9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uHxyx/ Looks fine to me. Are you sure your IE9 not running in compatibility mode?

Comment: It looks fine on my IE9, can you specify what problem you are having? Which formatting and which colors are not working?

Comment: Hi, the problem I'm having is that all the text is lined up one after the other, so the spacing, padding, margins etc aren't making the elements go to the correct position, which works fine in Firefox and Chrome. Only IE9 and IE8 are giving me this problem. No idea what's causing it at all. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, also tried it with compatibility mode on as well, but had no further improvements. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I ran a repair on my IE install, and it seems to be working now. Never use it, generally use Chrome or FF. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, in your CSS, don't overspecify your ID's (or any element for that matter)

so don't write `header#mainHeader` but just `#mainHeader`

Second,

Don't give your html element a background-color, set this on the body tag instead.

Third,

What is it exactly that doesn't display correctly?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I removed the header part from header#mainHeader and refreshed the page, but, still getting the same error. Basically, all the code in the IE browser just formats itself on the left hand side, each element under the next element. The sizing is working, and the background color to the body tag is working, but, none of the padding, margins etc work for me at all. I've tried it in IE8 as well, and no joy. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I ran a repair on my IE install, and it seems to be working now. Never use it, generally use Chrome or FF. Thanks for your replies.